# Why is my image gallery div overlapping the jQuery Mobile Page elements?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Please take a look at: http://mrwongsdeals.com/eventsearch.html

It appears fine in a browser however on a phone in landscape mode it is overlapping the buttons. How can I make it so that it does not do that?

I am using jQuery Mobile and in portrait mode everything looks Ok but in landscape things get messed up.

How can I make it so that the image scroller div at bottom does not over lap?

Answer (score 0):

it's **not** fine in a browser: if you resize your browser window and reduce its height, you'll see the same problem when your slideshow overlaps the form controls. the issue is simply in your css, not sure if it gets set automatically by the some plug-in you're using or else: `position absolute; top: XXXpx;` you need to make sure XXX is always more than the height of your form. Or wrap it inside the relatively positioned container if you need it to always stay in the same place in relation to the form. This is how you do it: [min - height with child set to position:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810382/min-height-with-child-set-to-positionabsolute)