# Is it possible to simulate `position: absolute` placement for element with `position: relative`?

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have to work on a software that generates tables (sort of...) and which must provide total control over the position of elements.

So far, we had constructs like this:

```
<div id="container" style="display: table-row">
  <div id="a" style="position: absolute"></div>
  <div id="b" style="position: absolute"></div>
  <div id="c" style="position: absolute"></div>
</div>
```

And some javascript code to place the `#a`, `#b` and `#c` elements within `#container` using `left` and `top` style directives.

That way, the elements could even be "inverted", that is: `#b` could be the first element on the left and `#a` the last, depending on some other rule.

However, this fails because those are taken out of the flow and so `#container` has a null height. Fair enough.

It seems [impossible to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810382/min-height-with-child-set-to-positionabsolute) that way, so I thought of using `position: relative` for the child elements, but doing so, the `left` and `top` style directives now refer to the initial element's position and are no more usable...

Have you ever had to deal with a similar situation ? What can I do to achieve the desired behavior ?

Thank you very much.

P.S : For those who wonder why we don't use `<table>` elements to represent a table, lets just say I wonder as well but have no power over that decision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things come to mind - both hacky and probably not super scalable:

1) Add `position: absolute` not in the CSS but in the JS - but before you do, fix the container to its pre-absolute, offset dimensions, so the height isn't lost

```
var container = $('#container');
container.height(container.height()).children().css('position', 'absolute');
```

2) Go with `position: relative`, but set their new positions relative to their original positions minus their offset.

```
var el = $('#some_el');
el.css({top: 0 - el.position().top});
```